# Render output comes out as a blank png even though the render result (F1) comes out perfectly

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, render-layers

I have two main render layers that I bring together using a mix node at 50% fac. I am compositing the two layers together however the output comes out blank even though the preview comes out correct. Attaching an image below, let me know if you need any other of my settings.[image][image]

Comment: Looks like compositor could have a file output node overwriting your result?

Comment: how do i check this??

Answer (score 1):

The file output node doesn't have anything attached to it, so it's going to overwrite with complete white.

When rendering an animation, the render result goes out through the *Composite* node, and a file named with the current frame number will be created in the folder you've designated under your render settings.

You don't need the *File Output* node, you can delete it.

Comment: i deleted it too but it still comes out blank. I rendered each layer seperately as a still to check, one of layers rendered correctly but the other shows transparent/blank

Comment: Oh, interesting.  You may try an Alpha Over node instead of Mix, then

Comment: i just tried the alpha over node but now it seems that only of those layers is rendering, the other is is stilling missing -- (yellow blob renders, transparent bubble doesn't ^ img)

Comment: I must admit my knowledge of render layers is still a bit lacking.  If I get some time I may try this out.